# how to arrange the triangle shaped drop down exact to the button

Tags: css, html

I can't see the drop down. 
Can any one please help me is the any way to do it. 
If so let me know the solution.

I want to arrange the triangle shaped one to be arranged exact down to the button. And the button is not visible when i place the dropdown class in the set-logo class.

You can observe the by removing the class dropdown in the below html. if anyone

```css
.Set-logo {
 display:inline-block;
 height:20px;
 width:19px;
 left:-100px;
 top:27%;
 border:1px solid #3d81a9;
 border-radius:50%;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:11px;
 line-height:18px;
 font-weight:600;
 background:#014d82;
 background:linear-gradient(#0272a5, #014d82);
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(#0272a5, #014d82);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#0272a5, #014d82);
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#fff!important;
 text-align:center;
}
.dropdown {
  position:absolute;
    display: block;
 width:25px;
 float:left;
}

.dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
       background-color: green;
     text-align: left;
        width: 90px;
       padding: 9px;
        margin: auto;
     border-radius: 4px;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
     border:1px solid #ddd;
    
}
.dropdown-content:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: 0px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #fff;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
 color:#FFFFFF;

}
```

```html
<div class="Set-logo  dropdown" ><a>S</a>

<div class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lock</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    
</div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove left:-100px to set logo class. this causes the button to hide.

You can achieve the requirement by changing position from right to left to the :after element and add margin-top to dropdown-content. Check the below snippet.

```css
.Set-logo {
     display:inline-block;
     height:20px;
     width:19px;
     border:1px solid #3d81a9;
     border-radius:50%;
     font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     font-size:11px;
     line-height:18px;
     font-weight:600;
     background:#014d82;
     background:linear-gradient(#0272a5, #014d82);
     background:-moz-linear-gradient(#0272a5, #014d82);
     background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#0272a5, #014d82);
     text-decoration:none;
     color:#fff!important;
     text-align:center;
    }
    .dropdown {
      position:absolute;
        display: block;
     width:25px;
     float:left;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
           background-color: green;
         text-align: left;
            width: 90px;
           padding: 9px;
            margin: auto;
            top:20px;
            margin-top:20px;
         border-radius: 4px;
         box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
         border:1px solid #ddd;
        
    }
    .dropdown-content:after {
      position: absolute;
      top: -21px;
      left: 0%;
      content: "";
      display: block;
      border-left: 15px solid transparent;
      border-right: 15px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 20px solid #000;
    }
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
     color:#FFFFFF;

    }
```

```html
   <div class="Set-logo  dropdown" ><a>S</a>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lock</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
        
    </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: you answer is correct can u please arrage the dropdown to the left on hover

Comment: It is already aligned to the left. If you need hoverd content to more left then add left:-5px; to .dropdown-content class

Comment: hope it fix your issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You should give `left`, `top` value to the `.dropdown` class will make it visible, as you used `position:absolute`.

```
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  float: left;
  left:10px;
  top:10px;
}
```

And made some changes in left position.

Your edited code here:

```css
.Set-logo {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 19px;
  left: -100px;
  top: 27%;
  border: 1px solid #3d81a9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: #014d82;
  background: linear-gradient(#0272a5, #014d82);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#0272a5, #014d82);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0272a5, #014d82);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff!important;
  text-align: center;
}
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  float: left;
  left:10px;
  top:10px;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: left;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 9px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  top:33px;
}
.dropdown-content:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -13px;
  left: 0px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid green;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.dropdown-content > li {
    list-style: outside none none;
}
```

```html
<div class="Set-logo  dropdown"><a>S</a>

  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Lock</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Logout</a>
    </li>

  </div>
</div>
```